# Is it possible to autocorrect the last word when sending an SMS?

Tags: sms, keyboard, auto-correct

iOS has the capability that, when pressing the send button in the Message app, that the last word gets autocorrected, without having to hit the spacebar after the last word. Is there a way to do this for Android, via a messaging app or particular keyboard, or some other means?

Comment: you have the freedom to install 3rd party keyboard app

Comment: @alecxs, that may be a good start. What's a keyboard app that does what is described in the question.

Comment: This has been requested many times (from as early as 2016) in various forums such as Reddit, keyboard forums but has not been addressed so far; to the best of my search. Maybe you could try [Grammarly keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grammarly.android.keyboard) that corrects as you type?

Comment: I tested Microsoft's SwitftKey keyboard for you and it does **not** help.  I also tested a couple SMS apps, including Textra, and none of them helped either.

Comment: BTW, although I understand why you want this feature, it does have its risks and downsides.  Auto-correct can often insert unintended (and sometime inappropriate) words, so I personally don't mind pressing the space bar to see what it proposes.  But it would be a nice option for people like yourself that are willing to assume the risks in exchange for the benefits.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket, thanks for checking. And I think you are right about downsides. I think it depends heavily on what the person is used to. I'm sure I'll be used to hitting spacebar or something like that before sending texts.

Answer (score 1):

Some Android devices auto-correct the last word when pressing the backspace button. So, if you type a word incorrectly and press space and it doesn't auto-correct the last word, you can press backspace and it will fix the error.

But this depends on the model you're using, in fact, some devices do the opposite: they undo the auto-correct.